# Robot Framework: Test execution hangs after sometime(after execution of 40 to 50 testcases) via Internet Explorer

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, robotframework, ie11

I am excuting a testsuite, which includes around 160 testcases via IE.

But the execution hangs after sometime. 
Testcases are simple ones,mostly to check the presence of elements or to get the text of an element.

```
IE11
IEServerdriver:version 3
Windows 10
```

Comment: Can you give proper details and paste the code if possible. also if you get any error give that too.

Comment: Sorry...i Cannot provide u the code..but this is the error i am getting "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid" before the execution hangs

Answer (score 2):

"**StaleElementReferenceException**" is throw when the webelement is no longer available(deleted) or modified from the DOM. This can happen due to page or a part of it has refreshed due to AJAX, Javascript, etc.

To handle this exception you will have to re-intialize the webelement for which you are getting the exception.

You can also try to use "try catch" to catch the StaleElementReferenceException.

Comment: thank u...i m using JS in my testcases to hide the navigation bar..is this causing issue here>??

Comment: not sure, it could be. unhide it and try to run your code.